# FLOW: Pass Account ID to Apex class

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

G'day everyone,

I have a Contact-triggered Flow which launches an Apex class to [Auto-Convert a Lead](https://github.com/Rakeshistom/Auto-Convert-Leads/blob/master/AutoConvertLeads).

This works nicely.

The Lead I am converting I'd like to relate to the Account ID of the Contact.

How to modify this class to capture the Account ID please?

And the [test class](https://github.com/Rakeshistom/Auto-Convert-Leads/blob/master/TestAutoConvertLeads) presumably?

Thanks very much,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of a very complete lead convert class (including Account Id) that you can copy-paste directly in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm).

```
global class ConvertLeadAction {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Convert Leads')
  global static List<ConvertLeadActionResult> convertLeads(List<ConvertLeadActionRequest> requests) {
    List<ConvertLeadActionResult> results = new List<ConvertLeadActionResult>();
    for (ConvertLeadActionRequest request : requests) {
      results.add(convertLead(request));
    }
    return results;
  }

  public static ConvertLeadActionResult convertLead(ConvertLeadActionRequest request) {
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(request.leadId);
    lc.setConvertedStatus(request.convertedStatus);

    if (request.accountId != null) {
        lc.setAccountId(request.accountId);
    }

    if (request.contactId != null) {
      lc.setContactId(request.contactId);
    }

    if (request.overWriteLeadSource != null && request.overWriteLeadSource) {
      lc.setOverwriteLeadSource(request.overWriteLeadSource);
    }

    if (request.createOpportunity != null && !request.createOpportunity) {
      lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(!request.createOpportunity);
    }

    if (request.opportunityName != null) {
      lc.setOpportunityName(request.opportunityName);
    }

    if (request.ownerId != null) {
      lc.setOwnerId(request.ownerId);
    }

    if (request.sendEmailToOwner != null && request.sendEmailToOwner) {
      lc.setSendNotificationEmail(request.sendEmailToOwner);
    }

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc, true);
    if (lcr.isSuccess()) {
      ConvertLeadActionResult result = new ConvertLeadActionResult();
      result.accountId = lcr.getAccountId();
      result.contactId = lcr.getContactId();
      result.opportunityId = lcr.getOpportunityId();
      return result;
    } else {
      throw new ConvertLeadActionException(lcr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
  }

  global class ConvertLeadActionRequest {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global ID leadId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global String convertedStatus;

    @InvocableVariable
    global ID accountId;

    @InvocableVariable
    global ID contactId;

    @InvocableVariable
    global Boolean overWriteLeadSource;

    @InvocableVariable
    global Boolean createOpportunity;

    @InvocableVariable
    global String opportunityName;

    @InvocableVariable
    global ID ownerId;

    @InvocableVariable
    global Boolean sendEmailToOwner;
  }

  global class ConvertLeadActionResult {
    @InvocableVariable
    global ID accountId;

    @InvocableVariable
    global ID contactId;

    @InvocableVariable
    global ID opportunityId;
  }

  class ConvertLeadActionException extends Exception {}
}
```

As far as a test goes, you just need to start off by creating a Lead and an Account, creating a list of `ConvertLeadActionResult` (it will contain just one element), then pass that in to the method, similar to the second link in your answer. We are not, strictly speaking, a code-writing service, but feel free to look around here on SFSE; it's likely someone's already written a unit test for you.

On the other hand, if you write a new unit test, and somehow get "stuck" on some kind of error, we'll be glad to help you solve the problem.

Comment: This is super-helpful @sfdcfox - thank you very much.